# Strange error running CPack after building a project.

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have the following *extremely* simple project:

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(myapp)

add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
install(TARGETS myapp RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "MyApp")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set(CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT DoSomething.cmake)

include(CPack)
```

#### myapp.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

#### DoSomething.cmake

```
message(WARNING "This message should be displayed.")
```

The project builds fine, but I run into issues when I attempt to run CPack:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:/tmp/myapp/build$ cpack
CPack: Create package using STGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Install scripts: DoSomething.cmake
CPack: - Install script: DoSomething.cmake
CPack Error: Error when generating package: MyApp
```

What does this mean? What was the error? CPack doesn't seem to have generated any logs or provide any further details. Commenting out the contents of `DoSomething.cmake` doesn't seem to make any difference.

According to [the documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT.html):

> `CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT`
>
> Extra CMake script provided by the user.
>
> If set this CMake script will be executed by CPack during its local [CPack-private] installation which is done right before packaging the files. The script is not called by e.g.: make install.

Why won't my package build and my warning message display?

Comment: Have you tried checking case sensitivity in case message isn't parsed, but MESSAGE is?

Comment: @hbdgaf: but then why does the error appear even when I comment out that line?

Comment: Use `cpack --verbose`

Answer (score 3):

An old question but the answer is you need to use an absolute path as in:

```
set(CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/DoSomething.cmake)
```